# Find out which GCP project is hosting which appengine or which GCS bucket

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, cname-record, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We have many projects inside our Organization GCP account.

We have many legacy GCS buckets and many legacy AppEngines hosted inside our various projects.

All these buckets and AppEngines are served via custom CNAME.

We use a separate DNS service outside GCP to manage our DNS records.

---

The problem we are facing today is, for these legacy buckets and legacy AppEngines, every DNS record says the CNAME value is `ghs.googlehosted.com`. We are now struggling to locate:

- which CNAME entry is for a bucket
- which CNAME entry is for an AppEngine
- which of our MANY GCP projects is hosting the bucket/AppEngine of that CNAME record

How do we find this out when there 200+ projects in the GCP account?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to export your billing account to BigQuery and analyze your dataset using SQL-like language.

Answer (score 0):

For Cloud Storage it might be useful for you to use [this command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web#set), that will retrieve the web semantics configuration for a bucket.

`gsutil web get gs://<bucket_name>`

Also for App Engine, you can use `gcloud app domain-mappings list` and [list the domain-mappings](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/domain-mappings/list) for a given project.

Comment: That is not the point. If we knew which project the domain is mapped to, then we wouldn't be having this question at all. This question was raised because we know the domain name, but we do not know which GCP project that domain name is mapped to